# Are 14 GB on my ssd enough space to install Ubuntu or can I install It on my harddrive to dualboot

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my PC to dual-boot it with Windows 10.
I have 14 GB space on my SSD(boot drive). Is this enough? And if it isn't can install it on my secondary hard drive to dual-boot it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: 14Gb in total of just base system? If the latter:yes, I used a 10gb root for years and years. If the first you will need to manage your personal data: you can put your private data on the 2nd disk too.

Comment: 18.04 Desktop minimal install requires 10GB disk space.

Comment: I am currently using 8.4GB in / on SSD, but have all data on HDD including some of the normally larger hidden folders like Firefox & Thunderbird profiles. I normally make / partition 25 to 30GB, but may have smaller partition where just testing another install. I do not have any games. You can have / on SSD & /home on HDD, but still need to regularly houseclean.  But do not make NTFS partition too small as Windows likes 30% free space. At 10% free, it may take forever to defrag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tell you, yesterday I installed Xubuntu 18.04 on a laptop with google chrome, firestorm, skype and clipgrab and all this needs 15,2GB, I think it's too little.. I think you must reestructure the partitions to make bigger this 14GB to 30GB or 40GB and I think it's enough if you dont need to save a lot of files, photos, games or software... I hope it could help you!